# Como evito que choquen los session start al querer acceder a variables con session

Tags: php, mvc, session

Tengo mi archivo main donde tengo un `session_start()` para acceder a las varibles como nombre, apellido etc. Y en un archivo donde hago la consulta de la base de datos quiero acceder a un `id` con `session` pero al iniciar el session start() me dice que ya se inició anteriormente.

Quiero quitar el session start de donde consulto la base de datos como podria hacer para acceder a esa variable.

```
 function read()
    {
      session_start();
      $id_escuela = $_SESSION['id_escuela'];
      require_once 'alumnoDTO.php';
      $query = "SELECT alumno.*, usuario.* from alumno alumno, escuela escuela, usuario usuario, director director WHERE usuario.id_usuario = alumno.id_usuario and alumno.id_escuela = escuela.id_escuela and director.id_escuela = escuela.id_escuela and director.id_escuela and alumno.id_escuela and director.id_escuela = '" . $id_escuela . "'";
      $objAlumnos = array();
      if (is_array($this->db->consultar($query)) || is_object($this->db->consultar($query))) {
        foreach ($this->db->consultar($query) as $key => $value) {
          $alumno = new AlumnoDTO();
          $alumno->id_alumno = $value['id_alumno'];
          $alumno->id_grupo = $value['id_grupo'];
          $alumno->id_escuela = $value['id_escuela'];
          $alumno->id_usuario = $value['id_usuario'];
          $alumno->foto_alumno = $value['foto_alumno'];
          $alumno->nombre_alumno = $value['nombre_alumno'];
          $alumno->appaterno_alumno = $value['appaterno_alumno'];
          $alumno->apmaterno_alumno = $value['apmaterno_alumno'];
          $alumno->calle_alumno = $value['calle_alumno'];
          $alumno->noexterior_alumno = $value['noexterior_alumno'];
          $alumno->nointerior_alumno = $value['nointerior_alumno'];
          $alumno->cp_alumno  = $value['cp_alumno'];
          $alumno->estado_alumno  = $value['estado_alumno'];
          $alumno->municipio_alumno  = $value['municipio_alumno'];
          $alumno->colonia_alumno  = $value['colonia_alumno'];
          $alumno->telefono_alumno = $value['telefono_alumno'];
          $alumno->email_alumno = $value['email_alumno'];
          $alumno->id_tipo_usuario = $value['id_tipo_usuario'];
          $alumno->fechanacimiento_alumno = $value['fechanacimiento_alumno'];
          $alumno->username_usuario = $value['username_usuario'];
          $alumno->password_usuario = $value['password_usuario'];
          array_push($objAlumnos, $alumno);
        }
      } else {
        $objAlumnos = null;
      }

      return $objAlumnos;
    }
```

Comment: Quita la imagen, y coloca el código por favor

Comment: Quiero acceder a la variable id_escuela pero sin el $_session para descartar el session_start() de ese archivo

Comment: Usualmente se usa `session_start` como primera línea de código en el archivo PHP. Parece que el problema es que estás requiriendo otros archivos o módulos que también tienen `sesion_start()`, lo cual indica que la estructura del proyecto no está bien. Esos módulos no deben ser subprogramas que hagan cosas por si solos sin control, si no que deben ser clases o funciones a las que les mandas parámetros desde el programa principal (main) y devuelven una respuesta.

Comment: ¿y si quitas ese `session_start()` que tienes forzado dentro de la función no te funciona ya todo bien?  Si te está diciendo que la sesion ya está iniciada entonces aprovéchalo y no vuelvas a intentar iniciarla creo yo.

Answer (score 0):

Borra todos los  `session_start();` que tengas en el codigo  y deja uno   al inicio del documento principal  justamente despues de abrir las etiquetas `php`

**Main.php**

```
<?php
  session_start();
  // Aqui el resto de tu codigo
?>
```

**Concejo que no has pedido:**

Evita utilizar variables de session adentro de las `funciones/metodos`

la `funcion read()` que has definido  las puedes modificar de la siguiente manera

```
function read($id_escuela =""){
    //aqui el codigo de la funcion 
}
```

Posteriormente puedes llamar dicha funcion de la siguiente manera

```
read($_SESSION['id_escuela']);
```